# GetQuote: Error in `.rowNamesDF<-`(x, value = value) : invalid 'row.names' length getsymbols

Tags: r, quantmod

I want to get all symbols from Qunatmod and make one dataframe with all getquote reseults.

```
symbols <- stockSymbols()
symbols <- symbols[,1]
symbols <- unique(symbols)

df <- getQuote((symbols))
```

"downloading set: 1 , 2 , 3 , Error in `.rowNamesDF<-`(x, value = value) : invalid 'row.names' length"

I get invalid row.names length error.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because there are symbols that can't be returned. This may also be related to volume limit requests on Yahoo. Check out the help page for details.

One approach to get around this is to leverage `try()`. Something like this works for me on the first 1000 symbols:

```
library(data.table)
dat <- lapply(symbols, function(x) try(getQuote(x)))
#create boolean for the symbols that retuned correctly
is_df <- sapply(dat, is.data.frame)
#bind them together
out <- rbindlist(dat[is_df], use.names = TRUE, fill = TRUE)
#add the names back
out[, Symbol := symbols[is_df]]
```